# What is the proper way of transferring large files(ML/AI models) from local server to aws?

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, api, rest

I have my own local server and I train ML/AI models with **python**. After training I store the model files that will help predicting results. I want to transfer that files to AWS and store them where my web application will be. The models will be trained and updated everyday. I don't want to train the models on AWS since it's expensive.

First of all is this approach applicable? If so, what is the best way of transferring that files?

Is there any way to send that kind of files with APIs?

Comment: What is the size of your models?

Comment: Start with S3, have a look at `boto3` and `s3fs` to transfer the files.

Comment: @StefanN between 100MB-1GB

Answer (score 1):

If you already use python I would suggest starting with the official AWS Python SDK called [boto3](https://pypi.org/project/boto3/#downloads).

You even have some examples in the docs:

- [Uploading files](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/guide/s3-uploading-files.html)
- [File transfer configuration](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/guide/s3.html)

Notice the latter, which enables the transfer to be multipart, especially good with files that are big.

From my experience, I can suggest you another simple tool called [rclone](https://rclone.org/).
Very simple to use, and from my experience sometimes even faster than using boto3.

Comment: Thanks for all the information. Just an FYI for everyone, I found datasync feature of amazon and I'll try that since it is synced with local folder.